# Erro ao passar uma estrutura por referência em C

Tags: c, struct

Estou aprendendo C. Todavia, tive um problema ao passar 
uma estrutura à uma função. Não consigo entender qual é o erro.

Ficarei grato, caso alguém me ajude. Me
desculpem pela má documentação. Entretanto, o código é bem simples.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define QT_EMP 2

/*Address*/
struct address{
    char country[20];
    char city[20];
    char st[20];
    unsigned long int zip;
};

/*Personal Data*/
struct pd{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    float size;
    float heavy;
};

/*Employes*/
struct emp{
    unsigned freedom: 1;
    unsigned is_emp : 1;
    struct pd data;
    struct address addr;
};

int menu ();
void del (struct emp *p, int i);
void init (struct emp *p);
int check (struct emp *p);
void show (struct emp *p);
void enter (struct emp *p, int i);

/*---------------------*/
/*--------MAIN---------*/
int main() {
    struct emp actors[QT_EMP];
    int choice = 0;
    init(&actors);

    while (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice) {
            /*Insert*/
            case 1:
            {
                int i;
                i = check(&actors);
                if (i != -1) enter(&actors, i);
                else printf("\nBad entry!");
                break;
            }

            /*Delete*/
            case 2:
            {
                del();              
                break;
            }

            /*Show*/
            case 3:
                show(&actors);
                break;

            /*Exit*/
            case 4:
                exit (1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
/*---------------------*/
/*---------------------*/

/*Delete*/
void del (struct emp *p, int i) {
    int i;
    printf("Type the indice: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    p[i]->is_emp = 0;
}

/*Initiate*/
void init (struct emp *p) {
    register int i;
    for (i = 0; i < QT_EMP; ++i) 
        p[i]->freedom = 1;
}
/*Check for empty indice*/
int check (struct emp *p) {
    register int i;
    for (i = 0; i < QT_EMP; ++i) {
        if (p[i]->freedom) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

/*Menu*/
int menu () {
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
        printf("------MENU------");
        printf("Select an option:\n");
        printf("1) Insert;\n");
        printf("2) Delete;\n");
        printf("3) Show;\n");
        printf("4) Exit. ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    return choice;
}

/*Show*/
void show (struct emp *p) {
    register int i;
    for (i = 0; i < QT_EMP; ++i)
        if (p[i]->freedom) {
            if (p[i]->is_emp) printf("\nEmployee");
            else printf("\nEx Employee!");
            printf("\n----Personal Data----");
            printf("\nName: %s", p[i]->data.name);
            printf("\nAge: %d", p[i]->data.age);
            printf("\nSize: %3f", p[i]->data.size);
            printf("\nHeavy: %f", p[i]->data.heavy);
            printf("\n----Adress----");
            printf("\nCountry: %s", p[i]->addr.country);
            printf("\nCity: %s", p[i]->addr.city);
            printf("\nStreet: %s", p[i]->addr.st);
            printf("\nZIP code: %d", p[i]->addr.zip);
        }
}

/*Enter the data of emp*/
void enter (struct emp *p, int i) {
    p->freedom = 0;
    p->is_emp = 1;
    /*Personal data*/
    printf("\n----Personal Data----");
    printf("\nName:");
    scanf("%20s", &p[i]->data.name);
    printf("\nAge: ");
    scanf("%d", &p[i]->data.age);
    printf("\nSize: ");
    scanf("%f", &p[i]->data.size);
    printf("\nHeavy: ");
    scanf("%f", &p[i]->data.heavy);
    /*Address*/
    printf("\n----Adress----");
    printf("\nCountry: ");
    scanf("%20s", &p[i]->addr.country);
    printf("\nCity: ");
    scanf("%20s", &p[i]->addr.city);
    printf("\nStreet: ");
    scanf("%20s", &p[i]->addr.st);
    printf("\nCity: ");
    scanf("%d", &p[i]->addr.zip);
}
```

Comment: o que esta dando errado?

Comment: Tente cortar o código para ter apenas a parte que tem o problema, bem como o erro que acompanha o problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código tem um monte de erros de compilação e mais algumas *warnings*.

Vamos por partes. Primeiro, troque essas linhas:

```
init(&actors);
i = check(&actors);
if (i != -1) enter(&actors, i);
show(&actors);
```

Por essas:

```
init(actors);
i = check(actors);
if (i != -1) enter(actors, i);
show(actors);
```

Ou seja, não use `&actors` dentro do `main`, basta usar apenas `actors`. O motivo disso é que arrays podem ser passados para funções como ponteiros, e as suas funções já esperam ponteiros.

Depois, na sua função `main`, há isso:

```
del();
```

Só que `del` tem dois parâmetros.

Aliás, olhe a sua função `del`:

```
void del (struct emp *p, int i) {
    int i;
    printf("Type the indice: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    p[i]->is_emp = 0;
}
```

Há duas variáveis `i`. A do parâmetro e a variável local. Acho que o que você queria era isso:

```
void del (struct emp *p) {
    int i;
    printf("Type the indice: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    p[i]->is_emp = 0;
}
```

E no `main`:

```
del(actors);
```

E também corrija o protótipo da função.

Finalmente, todos os lugares onde há `p[i]->` deveriam ser `p[i].` Há 23 lugares destes, inclusive esses dois (que você esqueceu o `[i]`):

```
p->freedom = 0;
p->is_emp = 1;
```

E no `scanf`, não use o `&` quando for ler uma string. Por exemplo:

```
scanf("%20s", p[i].data.name);
```

E também, ao usar o `scanf` ou o `printf` no `zip`, use `"%lu"` ao invés de `"%d"`.

Por fim, no `main`, ao invés de usar `exit (1);`, prefira colocar um `return 0;` no lugar. Também acho que no `main`, o seu `while (choice < 1 || choice > 4)` era para ser `while (1)`, e neste caso o `return 0;` que está no final é desnecessário.

Comment: Bem, falta de atenção mesmo. Eu passei o ponteiro de uma lista para uma função, uma vez que só era possível fazê-lo desta maneira. O livro, que estou usando como referência é excelente, todavia é muito antigo, de 1987. Obrigado pela ajuda, fico contente que tenha se disposto a me ajudar, em vez de criticar o post. Não apresentei os erros, visto que estavam em grandes quantidades, tal como você pode notar!